# How was the pressure cooker blast filmed?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, breakfast-at-tiffanys

In *Breakfast at Tiffany's* (1961), there is a scene where a pressure cooker suddenly blasts in front of two lead actors.

[image]

How was this pressure cooker blast filmed? Was there any risk of harm to the leads?

Comment: Doesn't look like a real explosion. Looks like they just added a water or compressed air hose and piped some smoke fog through it.